# deserialize xml into inherited classes from base class

Tags: c#, xml, xml-deserialization

I have the following xml structure:

```
<Root1>
    <name>Name1</name>
    <company>Comp1</company>
    <url>site.com</url>
    <elements>
        <element id="12" type="1">
            <url>site1.com</url>
            <price>15000</price>
            ...
            <manufacturer_warranty>true</manufacturer_warranty>
            <country_of_origin>Япония</country_of_origin>
        </element>
        <element id="13" type="2">
            <url>site2.com</url>
            <price>100</price>
            ...
            <language>lg</language>
            <binding>123</binding>
        </element>
    </elements>
</Root1>
```

I need to deserialize this xml into an object. You can see the element contains some equals field: `url` and `price`.
I would like to move these fields into a parent class and then inherit this class from other classes.

I created the class `Root1`:

```
namespace app1
{
    [Serializable]
    public class Root1
    {
        [XmlElement("name")] 
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("company")] 
        public string Company { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("url")] 
        public string Url { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("elements")]
        public List<Element> ElementList { get; set; }
    }
}
```

and then I created base class for `Element`:

```
[Serializable]
    public class Element
    {
        [XmlElement("url")] 
        public string Url { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("price")] 
        public string Price { get; set; }
    }
```

and then I inherited this class from other classes:

```
[Serializable]
public class Element1 : Element
{
    [XmlElement("manufacturer_warranty")] 
    public string mw { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("country_of_origin")] 
    public string co { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class Element2 : Element
{
    [XmlElement("language")] 
    public string lg { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("binding")] 
    public string bind { get; set; }
}
```

When I deserialize this xml to object `Root1` I get the object - it is ok.
But the List of `Elements` contains only `Element` objects not `Element1` and `Element2` objects.

How I do deserialize this xml so list of `Elements` contains `Element1` and `Element2` objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@netwer It is not working for you because the code suggested above generates the xml (below) that does not match with the one you use for deserialization (see how it specifies derived types in for element).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Root1>
  <name>Name1</name>
  <company>Comp1</company>
  <url>site.com</url>
  <elements>
    <element d3p1:type="Element1" xmlns:d3p1="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
      <url>site1.com</url>
      <price>15000</price>
      <manufacturer_warranty>true</manufacturer_warranty>
      <country_of_origin>Япония</country_of_origin>
    </element>
    <element d3p1:type="Element2" xmlns:d3p1="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
      <url>site2.com</url>
      <price>100</price>
      <language>lg</language>
      <binding>123</binding>
    </element>
  </elements>
</Root1>
```

So you will either have to match this format with source xml (change code or API that returns this xml data) or take another approach. Even if you manage to do with former one you have to find a way to access Element1 or Element2 specific properties.

newRoot1.Elements.ElementList[i] will always let you access only price and url since your list is of Element type. Although run time type of ElementList[i] will be Element1 or Element2, how will you detect that?

Here I suggest alternative approach. Irrespective of whether your application (client) generates this xml or the server which returns it on hitting API, you should be able to gather information on all the fields applicable to an 'element' object. If it is your code you know it already, if it is an API there must be a document for it. This way you only have to create one 'Element' (no derived classes) and put proper checks (mostly string.IsNullOrEmpty()) before accessing Element class property values in your code. Only the properties that are present in your xml 'element' element will be considered rest will be set to NULL for that instance.

```
[Serializable]
public class Element
{
   [XmlElement("url")]
   public string Url { get; set; }

   [XmlElement("price")] 
   public string Price { get; set; }

   [XmlElement("manufacturer_warranty")]
   public string mw { get; set; }

   [XmlElement("country_of_origin")]
   public string co { get; set; }

   [XmlElement("language")]
   public string lg { get; set; }

   [XmlElement("binding")]
   public string bind { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: @netwer - Could not comment on previous messages due to low reputation.

Comment: thank you for your very detailed answer!
yes, I changed my objects model. Now it looks like your example.

Comment: Please close the thread If things are working for you now. Don't leave it unattended.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use [`XmlIncludeAttribute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlincludeattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) like this:

```
[XmlInclude(typeof(Element1))]
public class Element
{
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. You think that I should include typeof(Element 1) in Element1?

Comment: @netwer ... try it in `Element` class. I updated my answer. please try it and let me know if it works for you.

Answer (score 1):

Here is xml and code.  I like to first serialize with test data, then deserialize.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Root1>
  <name>Name1</name>
  <company>Comp1</company>
  <url>site.com</url>
  <element d2p1:type="Element1" xmlns:d2p1="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <url>site1.com</url>
    <price>15000</price>
    <manufacturer_warranty>true</manufacturer_warranty>
    <country_of_origin>Япония</country_of_origin>
  </element>
  <element d2p1:type="Element2" xmlns:d2p1="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <url>site2.com</url>
    <price>100</price>
    <language>lg</language>
    <binding>123</binding>
  </element>
</Root1>
```

Code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.IO;


namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
            Root1 root1 = new Root1() {
                Name = "Name1",
                Company = "Comp1",
                Url = "site.com",
                ElementList = new List<Element>() {
                    new Element1() {
                        Url = "site1.com",
                        Price = "15000",
                        mw = "true",
                        co = "Япония"
                    },
                    new Element2() {
                        Url = "site2.com",
                        Price = "100",
                        lg = "lg",
                        bind = "123"
                    }
                }
            };

            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Root1));
            StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(FILENAME);
            XmlSerializerNamespaces _ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
            _ns.Add("", "");
            serializer.Serialize(writer, root1, _ns);
            writer.Flush();
            writer.Close();
            writer.Dispose();

            XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Root1));
            XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(FILENAME);
            Root1 newRoot1 = (Root1)xs.Deserialize(reader);


        }

    }
    [XmlRoot("Root1")]
    public class Root1
    {
        [XmlElement("name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("company")]
        public string Company { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("url")]
        public string Url { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("element")]
        public List<Element> ElementList { get; set; }
    }
    [XmlInclude(typeof(Element1))]
    [XmlInclude(typeof(Element2))]
    [XmlRoot("element")]
    public class Element
    {
        [XmlElement("url")]
        public string Url { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("price")]
        public string Price { get; set; }
    }
    [XmlRoot("element1")]
    public class Element1 : Element
    {
        [XmlElement("manufacturer_warranty")]
        public string mw { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("country_of_origin")]
        public string co { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot("element2")]
    public class Element2 : Element
    {
        [XmlElement("language")]
        public string lg { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("binding")]
        public string bind { get; set; }
    }



}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. I'm found many examples like your example, but all of it does not work for me. I think I do anything wrong. I hope I found my errors and resolve it.

Comment: Do you need both 'elements' and 'element'?  My code only produces 'element'.  I use XmlElement instead of XmlArray.  XmlArray produces the extra tag.  I can change code if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Code below matches better with your posted XML.  You need to compare the generated xml with your xml.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.IO;


namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
            Root1 root1 = new Root1()
            {
                Name = "Name1",
                Company = "Comp1",
                Url = "site.com",
                cElement = new Elements() { 
                   ElementList = new List<Element>() {
                       new Element1() {
                           Url = "site1.com",
                           Price = "15000",
                           mw = "true",
                           co = "Япония"
                       },
                       new Element2() {
                           Url = "site2.com",
                           Price = "100",
                           lg = "lg",
                           bind = "123"
                       }
                    }

                }
            };

            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Root1));
            StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(FILENAME);
            XmlSerializerNamespaces _ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
            _ns.Add("", "");
            serializer.Serialize(writer, root1, _ns);
            writer.Flush();
            writer.Close();
            writer.Dispose();

            XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Root1));
            XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(FILENAME);
            Root1 newRoot1 = (Root1)xs.Deserialize(reader);

        }

    }
    [XmlRoot("Root1")]
    public class Root1
    {
        [XmlElement("name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("company")]
        public string Company { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("url")]
        public string Url { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("elements")]
        public Elements cElement { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot("elements")]
    public class Elements
    {
        [XmlElement("element")]
        public List<Element> ElementList { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlInclude(typeof(Element1))]
    [XmlInclude(typeof(Element2))]
    [XmlRoot("element", Namespace = "")]
    public class Element
    {
        [XmlElement("url")]
        public string Url { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("price")]
        public string Price { get; set; }
    }
    [XmlRoot("element1", Namespace = "")]
    public class Element1 : Element
    {
        [XmlElement("manufacturer_warranty")]
        public string mw { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("country_of_origin")]
        public string co { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot("element2", Namespace = "")]
    public class Element2 : Element
    {
        [XmlElement("language")]
        public string lg { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("binding")]
        public string bind { get; set; }
    }

}​
```